# How to simplify long expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra

~ means NOT, and + means Or

I want to simplify the following with the Boolean Laws-

~A~B~C~D + ~A~B~CD + ~A~BCD + ~AB~CD + ~ABC~D +~ABCD + A~B~CD + A~BC~D + AB~CD + ABCD

So I've simplified it until
~A~B~C + ~ABC + A~BC~D + DB~C + A~CD + ABD + ~A~BCD

However I couldn't find a way to simplify it down to the form I found from the K-map method which is:

~A~B~C + ~ABC + A~BC~D + ~AD + BD + ~CD

I see that the first three variables are equal (~A~B~C + ~ABC + A~BC~D), but I don't see how I could simplify

DB~C + A~CD + ABD + ~A~BCD

into

~AD + ~BD + ~CD

Comment: You may want to clarify that `*` is `and` and `+` is `or`. Unsure since, in some places, you skip the `*` altogether (such as with `~BD`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Formal Logic 101, not computer programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to be wrong. I tried it using 4 variable K-map.
and i got -

```
A`B`C`+ A'BC+ AB'CD'+ C'D + A'D + A'CD
```